# How to Install JavaFX on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: java, javafx, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install JavaFX on WSL Ubuntu
I just updated and upgraded all my packages and checked that OpenJDK is up to date. 
If I try to compile anything for JavaFX I get errors like this.

[image]

[image]

Below is my Java Version.

[image]

Any help would be great cause I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: do you have the org.openjfx jars in your classpath?

Comment: I don't think so, how do I modify the classpath

Comment: Install the [Liberica JDK](https://bell-sw.com/), it still ships with JavaFX (renamed LibericaFX for legal reasons). No extra software required.

Answer (score 0):

You should install OpenJFX first

```
sudo apt install openjfx
```

openjdk-11 comes without javafx/openjfx by default.

Comment: You try to build something from source, so maybe you can tell us what you are using for dependency resolution. Maven, gradle?

Answer (score 0):

in our course at POLIMI  we solved so:

https://github.com/ingconti/JavaFXWithImagesAndText/blob/master/ReadMeForWSL.md

by Michele Alziati and me.